# Вылетает ошибка ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Сделал тестовое приложение на RoR. Отлично запускается и работает.

Но если скачать его с гитхаба, установить зависимости путём bundle install, затем миграцию и запустить, то получаю следующую ошибку:
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken, когда пытаюсь авторизироваться или создать пользователя.

У меня не определены контроллеры sessions и registrations.

Вот [приложение](https://github.com/1ocke/simple_pm) на гитхабе

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:215:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:247:in `handle_unverified_request'
devise (4.7.2) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:255:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:242:in `verify_authenticity_token'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:428:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Callbacks>'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block in halting'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `block in invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `each'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:513:in `invoke_before'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:33:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:180:in `instrument'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (6.0.3.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:254:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:33:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in <class:Constraints>'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:49:in `block in serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.8) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:40:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:648:in `call'
activerecord (6.0.3.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:567:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:32:in `call'
web-console (4.0.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.0.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.0.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.0.3) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:80:in `tagged'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (6.0.3.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (6.0.3.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
webpacker (4.2.2) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (6.0.3.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'


Parameters:

{"authenticity_token"=>"PeI6W0K1pPEvN2ZLP3+I1Q5wC6GjOdS3JbszyjMuwQrCKIf7TNvFlPjYFnblnXIXHvEtZO03IKbaSPJKwCepvQ==",
 "user"=>{"email"=>"letzabelin@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Log in"}
```

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста к вопросу полный бэктрейс ошибки

Comment: @Василиса добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пришлось таки поднять у себя ваш проект, чтобы разобраться. В чем причина - из-за Стимулуса вы добавили в конфиг

```
config.session_store :cache_store
```

Этот параметр определяет, где хранится сессия, по умолчанию это `cookie_store`, вы его изменили на `cache_store`

Но при этом кеширование изначально в новом проекте не включено. Чтобы его запустить, после установки проекта на новой машине нужно выполнить

```
rails dev:cache
```

И всё заработает

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Вы, мне кажется, единственная в ру стэке, кто отвечает на вопросы по руби) Не подскажете, а как Вы поняли, что дело в стимулусе? По бэктрейсу? Ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: @1ocke всегда пожалуйста, заходите ещё :) Стараюсь, потому как помню, как трудно начинать было. Но вообще очень рекомендую прокачать инглиш и искать ответы на нём - уж больно мало инфы по руби/рельсам на русском

Comment: @1ocke нет, бэктрейс особо ничего не дал. Погуглила, стянула проект, исключила все остальные проблемы и нашла где-то ответ про `session_store` при такой же ошибке, только там проблема была в другом. Посмотрела ваши коммиты и увидела, что вы его изменили при добавлении стимулуса

Comment: да, Вы правы, на русском информации практически и нет. Зато есть Вы!) Спасибо)